# Android studio manifest file all red

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

[image]

Everything went red after I integrated Google login.

Comment: do you have a string with name `google_maps_key`?

Comment: No, and after i delete that line, it is generated again when i compile the code.

Comment: are you editing the manifest contained in `build` or `bin` ?

Comment: Its in build, i think it's somehow related to that i added on folder : New > Google > Google maps activity. How do I remove it?

Comment: if ti is in build, you are editing the wrong Manifest.

Comment: What's the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't have the `google_maps_key` in your string.xml

You have to add it or to remove the call of this string